# Dialog Fragment with and EditText shows keyboard automatically after load

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, android-dialogfragment

I have a DialogFragment that has a view with an `EditText` in it. Every time I show the dialog the edittext has focus and the keyboard comes up.

How can i stop it from coming up automatically?

I tried putting `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` in my manifest for the activity that creates the fragment but that had no effect

this is my dialog fragment

```
public class RegDialog extends DialogFragment {

OnRegComplete mRegComplete;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try{
        mRegComplete = (OnRegComplete)activity;
    }catch(ClassCastException e){
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnRegComplete");
    }
}

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle state){
    Dialog d = new Dialog(getActivity());
    d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    d.setContentView(R.layout.registration);
    d.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    return d;
}

public interface OnRegComplete{
    void onRegComplete();
}
```

}

this is my layout

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:text="Registration" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="State"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/reg_title" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="Station"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="County"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
    android:text="@string/reg_btn" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:text="Password"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/mobile_mapr_logo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had to give focus to a view above the edit text using

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

in the view

Answer (score 13):

Use this code to hide it programmatically

```
Dialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
your_edit_text.clearFocus();
```

How about if you changed in the manifest to:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
```

That helped me with some keyboard issues i had :-)